# Measure LEN of String between dashes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to search for wrongly formatted phone numbers. I can get the lengths of the string before the first dash and after the last. I am drawing a blank on the middle digits. This is what I have so far.

```
 CREATE TABLE Phone
 ( PhoneNum varchar(12) NULL)

 INSERT INTO Phone (PhoneNum ) 
 VALUES ('11-1111-2369'),('236-5469-111'), ('239-279-7777')

 SELECT LEN(LEFT(PhoneNum,CHARINDEX('-',PhoneNum)-1)), 
 LEN(Right(PhoneNum,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(PhoneNum))-1)), PhoneNum FROM 
 Phone
```

I am looking to see if the length of anything in between the two dashes is anything other than LEN = 3

This seems to work

```
SELECT LEN( REPLACE(phonenum,'-','')) -(LEN(LEFT(PhoneNum,charindex('-
',PhoneNum)-1)) + LEN(Right(PhoneNum,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(PhoneNum))-1))) ,
   PhoneNum from phone
```

Comment: Hint: `SUBSTRING`

Comment: Could you add the expected result, because am little confused on your expectation

Comment: Are all your phone numbers in the form `(digits)-(digits)-(digits)`?

Comment: @Pரதீப் Surely if the question asks for the length of the string between dashes, the desired result for `11-1111-2369` is 4, for `236-5469-111` is 4, for `239-279-7777` is 3. To the OP: if you're actually after something else, please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Yeah I don't understand what the confusion is either. The question: How to measure the string length between two dashes? is pretty straightforward.

Comment: yes @hvd digits - digits - digits. I can find bad phone numbers if they aren't in that format but if someone enters something like 234-22-34456 That total length falls within the parameters of a normal phone # but the LEN of the middle digits is off

Comment: @JacobH - Are you sure about the requirement ? There is no need to find the length. OP is original requirement is to find the bad phone numbers

Comment: @BrianMichaels That allows you to do exactly what Horaciux now answered, just relying on `LEN('a-b-c') = LEN('a')+1+LEN('b')+1+LEN('c')`, where `a`, `b` and `c` can be replaced by any number of digits.

Comment: @Pரதீப் Yes because those two things are the same if you read the post. OP is looking for "bad" phone numbers where the length of the value between the two dashes is not correct (3). So he wants to get the length between the two dashes. If you run the code above, you will see the OP got the length before the first dash, and the length after the 2nd dash, but not between the two. Hence why he made the post. There's no confusion on my end at all.

Comment: Finding length is never going to help to find the badly formatted phone numbers. ex: `abc5-123-1234`. Here is the correct approach `PhoneNum not like '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`

Comment: @Pரதீப் That's why I asked if all phone numbers were in the form `(digits)-(digits)-(digits)`, to which the OP answered "yes". We *know* that the only bad formatting in the phone numbers is an incorrect length, so we don't need to check. Your correct approach does not appear correct, since the OP has now stated that the check should only be on the length of the middle component.

Comment: @Pரதீப் That is correct I can  search for alpha character with LIKE '%[a-z]%' so any number containing that I can flag as incorrect. I can all so measure total length and number of dashes to also flag bad numbers.  That is why I was looking for length of the middle numbers. It was the only thing I couldn't find. I think I have it resolved now with the help of all you guys. The query I used in my edits seems to always work. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sure what is the right combination but for example assuming xxx-xxx-xxxx

```
select * from phone where PhoneNum like '___-___-____'
```

will get correct phones while

```
  select * from phone where PhoneNum not like '___-___-____'
```

the incorrect ones

Also, this calculate the len between dashes

```
 SELECT  
 len(phoneNum) --whole string len
 - LEN(LEFT(PhoneNum,CHARINDEX('-',PhoneNum)-1)) -- removes left part
 - LEN(Right(PhoneNum,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(PhoneNum))-1)) -- removes right part
 -2 --remove both dashes     
 , PhoneNum FROM  Phone
```

Reference to LIKE operator wildcards:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql

Comment: Could also use `'[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`.

Comment: @BaconBits definitely it would be more accurate.

Comment: I didn't know you could use the underscores like that. Thank you!

Comment: @BrianMichaels I just add a reference for you to see more detail. I'm glad it helps

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking to see if the length of anything in between the two dashes is anything other than LEN = 3

In that case, an alternative approach is to not calculate the length at all, but to use pattern matching:

```
SELECT PhoneNum
FROM Phone
WHERE PhoneNum NOT LIKE '%-___-%'
```

Note: unlike Horaciux's answer, I'm using `%` in the pattern. This handles the first and third bit of the pattern varying in length.